# Windows 10 Hands Free AG Audio not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

I've been using a set of Plantronics Voyager Focus headphones fine until last week. I was able to use both the high-quality headphone driver and the AG driver for MS teams just fine.

My laptop was 'upgraded' by work last week and now I have a problem with the AG hands-free driver - it connects via Bluetooth but I don't hear any sound (the stereo headphones still work just fine). The headphones connect via Bluetooth when it boots up just fine, but every time I select the AG driver I hear the beep that makes me think it is reconnecting again. Initially I thought this was an issue with MS Teams but even with that shutdown, the same problem is happening. So far I have tried:

- Updating the headphone firmware
- Windows updates to make sure everything there is up to date
- Updating MS Teams
- Making sure all the settings on the Windows Sound control panel are up to date (If I read one more article telling me to turn the volume up I will throw my laptop out the window!)
- Restarting all the Bluetooth services

Has anyone got any other ideas? I suspect my IT department just have a standard image they use for all laptops so I'm suspecting it is a Bluetooth issue. Any ideas greatly appreciated!

I've read some MS knowledge base articles that suggest rolling your laptop back to the last working system restore point. Really? Just to get some headphones working?

Comment: Possibly related issue observed. [Microsoft Answers Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/hands-free-ag-audio-mode-broken-after-windows/e160c131-66dd-4763-9a7b-3439d737bafc). Doesn't seem to specify an exact solution. I have the same issue with a pair of WH-1000MX3 headphones.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to `settings`->`Devices`->`Bluetooth and other devices`
Under that, there will be **Audio**, select the audio device and select on remove device.
After that pair and connect with it again.

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that your laptop was "Upgraded" by work, does this include any new software being installed, or did they install new drivers / flash the bios? | Alternatively, if they have used a basic windows 10 image, this usually installs old / basic drivers that don't always fit what the manufacturer expects. (This is the case for atleast Dell laptops) This has, in my experience at my current work, caused external devices to behave weirdly on laptops.

I would suggest trying to downgrade to the last stable version you had of your bluetooth driver earlier. What model is your laptop? Try to find it's newest manufacturer specified audio / bt driver on their website.